# Install plugin remotely

Tags: plugins, installation, remote

I have seen a couple services ( ManageWP, BlogVault ) where we supply them with the admin login details to our WordPress site and they programmatically install their respective plugin and then connect to it. I am working on a project where I have to migrate a few hundred WordPress sites, doing them individually will be a time consuming task so I am trying to automate it.

I have looked into XMLRPC and cURL but have hit a wall. For e.g I can script the login form using cURL, but then don't know a way forward to install the plugin. With XMLRPC the wp.UploadFile method only allows jpeg, png and gif files to be uploaded. Will appreciate if someone can point me the correct direction.

Comment: Have you considered using the REST API? Or WP CLI?

Comment: @TomJNowell the issue is that not all hosts will have wp-cli. Also the main stumbling block is that I'll be given only WordPress login details. I haven't looked into REST API, but last when I checked there was no endpoint to handle the plugins. If possible can you point me to the documentation around installing a plugin via REST API?

Comment: You're going to have a very difficult time if all you have is a login

Comment: Why wouldn’t Selenium (or its equivalent) do what you need? Write a script to login, install the plugin, and logout.

Comment: For anyone who can install wp-cli on the server, here's an article I found on how to do it: https://www.shawnhooper.ca/2017/08/08/wp-cli-remote/