# Install plugin on remote wordpress

Tags: wp-cli, wp-remote-get, remote, wp-remote-request, remote-login

I want to install a plugin using wp-cli (or anything else) on a WordPress based website. I have URL, admin-user, admin-pass only. (no FTP/ssh). I want to do it programmatically, without going into the browser. I am able to do so on my local WordPress install.

Comment: This isn't going to be possible via WP CLI without SSH access, there are services that can do it but you need to install a plugin for them to start working. Unfortunately, plugin/service/product recommendations are not in scope. Have you tried just logging in with the admin user/pass and going to `plugin->add`? What's the context behind this, or the problem this solves?

Comment: @TomJNowell Actually, I want to write a script which accepts above three parameters (URL, admin-user, admin-pass) and install a plugin on that WP instance. The most obvious way I found was wp-cli, but I realized that it required ssh access or wp-cli on both servers installed.

Comment: What problem does that solve? Are you trying to implement a deployment strategy? An easy way for people to install a plugin you're selling? What's the context?

Comment: Yes, I want to create a WordPress management solution, or at least learn it how some popular solutions are working, like managewp and wpmudev hub etc etc.

Comment: @Abdul Waheed You said "but I want to do it from server, not by going to browser". Why do you want to "_do it_" from the server? What assumptions are you making?

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of stepping into the unknown, I reckon that you are over-complicating things-full remote access to the WP database sounds like the most effective solution. What could you not do if you had access to the database?

Having said that, you have a duty to have done your own research, and to have explained what you have tried &/or how you have approached a solution. For instance, have you looked at any of the free and/or “open source” solutions (the five minutes I spent on research revealed “MainWP” or “Shift8 Remote Management” as possible candidates). I sense that you have come in search of the holy grail, and while people are only too happy to assist you, there is no such thing as a “free lunch”.

Comment: Hi @Tedinoz, The main thing is file management here. I want to install a plugin on a remote site (programmatically) from my server using any solution (no matter, wp/php or any other app like wp-cli). I have wp-admin access to that site, I can do that by going to browser, but I want to do it from server, not by going to browser. don't know if wp-cli is installed on that server or not. This is where wp-cli failed. (I have tried wp-cli)

Comment: Both of above plugins require a plugin already installed on remote site, first-step. Which I want to do programmatically.

Comment: similar question, but with no answer unfortunately. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/275567/install-plugin-remotely

Comment: What about something like Selenium?

Comment: Selenium. Proof positive that if you have the admin name and password, then the world is your oyster. This YouTube video [“Selenium Java Tests with WordPress”](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=_1J_cmkaYe0) shows how installing a plugin would be like falling off a log. This version is Java, but Selenium is available in several incarnations, I believe.